# You must upload an iMessage screenshot for 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd Generation) displays

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect

I recently tried to upload my phonegap app and now it has a new **iMessage App** section that requires photos that I dont know how to find and where to create from.

```
The items listed below are required for submission:
You must upload a screenshot for 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation) displays.
You must upload an iMessage screenshot for 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd Generation) displays.
You must upload a screenshot for 6.5-inch iPhone displays.
You must upload an iMessage screenshot for 6.5-inch iPhone displays.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Plugins used

```
cordova-plugin-console 
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
cordova-plugin-camera 
cordova-plugin-media-capture 
cordova-plugin-contacts 
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-dialogs 
cordova-plugin-file 
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 
cordova-plugin-geolocation 
cordova-plugin-globalization 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 
cordova-plugin-media 
cordova-plugin-network-information 
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 
cordova-plugin-statusbar 
cordova-plugin-vibration 
cordova-plugin-google-analytics
```

Comment: You can use the various simulators

Comment: Ok my question is more along the lines of why is it asking for the iMessage App screen captures? What changed? Is there some setting in Cordova/Phonegap that I am missing?

Comment: It seems that Apple has detected that your app contains an iMessage extension.

Comment: I updated the question to show the list of plugins I am using, none of these are using iMessage to my knowledge